# How to change server name in IIS 8.5, after cloning it from another server

Tags: iis-8

We have configured a new server Pankaj-02A from cloning the server Pankaj-TESTB
Have changed the hostname of new server following the url:-
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/234142/updating-iis-after-you-change-the-computer-name

But still see the name of old server in one place under IIS

[image]

How to change that?

Answer (score 12):

Not sure if its the only way but in IIS under the "Connections" pane **>** right click on the Server Name (available below "Start Page" node) **>** select "Remove Connection" (Refer screenshot):

[image]

Then click on <kbd>Yes</kbd> to the prompt.  Then right click on "Start Page" and select "Connect to a Server...".  Now enter the new name of the server. Click <kbd>Next</kbd> and then click <kbd>Finish</kbd>.

Comment: Worked for me.  This should be the accepted answer.  To clear some confusion, these instructions are for the Connections pane all the way on the left (the first picture in OP), not the "Recent Connections" pane on the start page.

Comment: one more step after this, close IIS and click yes when it asks you to save the connection list.

Answer (score 4):

You can just rename the server in IIS. Click on the server name and press <kbd>F2</kbd> or rightclick-rename.

Comment: LOL! This worked for me! Thanks.

Comment: Actually this is the quickest and easiest way. Don't forget to close the window to save the changes.